# How do I avoid copying the array during every merge in a bottom-up mergesort?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

I have the following code, which implements a bottom-up mergesort:

```
#include "sort.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CUTOFF 8
#define MIN(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))

void merge(uint8_t *, uint8_t *, size_t, size_t, size_t, cmpfn);

// sort LEN elements of A, of SZ bytes each, using CMP to perform the
// comparisons
void merge_sort(void *a, size_t len, size_t sz, cmpfn cmp) {
  uint8_t *buf = malloc(len * sz);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i += CUTOFF) {
    insertion_sort((uint8_t *) a + i * sz, MIN(CUTOFF, len - i), sz, cmp);
  }
  for (size_t w = CUTOFF; w < len; w *= 2) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i + w < len; i += w * 2) {
      merge((uint8_t *) a + i * sz, buf, MIN(w * 2, len - i), w, sz, cmp);
    }
  }
  free(buf);
}

void merge(uint8_t *a, uint8_t *buf, size_t len, size_t mid, size_t sz,
          cmpfn cmp) {
  if (cmp(a + mid * sz, a + (mid - 1) * sz) >= 0) {
    return;
  }

  size_t i = 0, j = mid, k = 0;

  memcpy(buf, a, len * sz);
  while (i < mid && j < len) {
    if (cmp(buf + j * sz, buf + i * sz) < 0) {
      memcpy(a + k * sz, buf + j++ * sz, sz);
    } else {
      memcpy(a + k * sz, buf + i++ * sz, sz);
    }
    ++k;
  }
  if (j == len) {
    memcpy(a + k * sz, buf + i * sz, (mid - i) * sz);
  }
}
```

Currently, during every call of `merge`, the code copies the contents of the array into `buf`. I know that in a top-down recursive approach, you can switch the order of the two arrays when calling merge to avoid the copy. How can I achieve this with an iterative approach?

EDIT: I got it working now, and I've posted the answer. If anyone has any suggestions or notices any drawbacks, feedback would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working now.

```
#include "sort.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CUTOFF 8
#define SWAP(a, b)                                                             \
  do {                                                                         \
    typeof(a) temp = a;                                                        \
    a = b;                                                                     \
    b = temp;                                                                  \
  } while (0);
#define MIN(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))

void merge(uint8_t *, uint8_t *, uint8_t *, size_t, size_t, size_t, cmpfn);

// sort LEN elements of A, of SZ bytes each, using CMP to perform the
// comparisons
void merge_sort(void *a, size_t len, size_t sz, cmpfn cmp) {
  void *p = a;
  uint8_t *buf = malloc(len * sz);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i += CUTOFF) {
    insertion_sort((uint8_t *) a + i * sz, MIN(CUTOFF, len - i), sz, cmp);
  }
  for (size_t w = CUTOFF; w < len; w *= 2) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i + w <= len; i += w * 2) {
      merge(buf + i * sz, (uint8_t *) a + i * sz, (uint8_t *) a + (i + w) * sz,
            w, MIN(w, len - (i + w)), sz, cmp);
    }
    SWAP(a, buf);
  }
  if (a != p) {
    memcpy(p, a, len * sz);
    buf = a;
  }
  free(buf);
}

void merge(uint8_t *res, uint8_t *a, uint8_t *b, size_t na, size_t nb,
           size_t sz, cmpfn cmp) {
  if (na > 0 && nb > 0 && cmp(b, a + (na - 1) * sz) >= 0) {
    memcpy(res, a, na * sz);
    memcpy(res + na * sz, b, nb * sz);
    return;
  }

  size_t i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

  while (i < na && j < nb) {
    if (cmp(b + j * sz, a + i * sz) < 0) {
      memcpy(res + k * sz, b + j++ * sz, sz);
    } else {
      memcpy(res + k * sz, a + i++ * sz, sz);
    }
    ++k;
  }
  if (i == na) {
    memcpy(res + k * sz, b + j * sz, (nb - j) * sz);
  } else if (j == nb) {
    memcpy(res + k * sz, a + i * sz, (na - i) * sz);
  }
}
```

Comment: The code is still copying data to res[] in merge(). I posted an answer that avoids these copy operations.

Answer (score 0):

Example code. Insertion sort run size is set to 16 or 32 so there are an even number of merge passes. A second array is allocated one time, and the direction of merge changes with each pass by swapping pointers to avoid copy  operations during merge (except for the case of a single run at the end of a merge pass).

```
int GetPassCount(int n)                 /* return # passes */
{
    int i = 0;
    for(int s = 1; s < n; s <<= 1)
        i += 1;
    return(i);
}

void MergeSort(int a[], int n)
{
int * b;                                /* ptr to second array */
int * t;                                /* temp ptr for swap */
int sz;                                 /* run size  */

    if(n < 2)                           /* if size < 2 return */
        return;
    b = malloc(n * sizeof(int));        /* allocate second array */
    /* set run size so merge sort is even number of passes */
    sz = ((GetPassCount(n) & 1) != 0) ? 32 : 16;
    {                                   /* insertion sort */
        int l, r;
        int i, j;
        int t;
        for (l = 0; l < n; l = r) {
            r = l + sz;
            if (r > n)r = n;
            l--;
            for (j = l + 2; j < r; j++) {
                t = a[j];
                i = j-1;
                while(i != l && a[i] > t){
                    a[i+1] = a[i];
                    i--;
                }
                a[i+1] = t;
            }
        }
    }

    for( ; sz < n; sz *= 2){            /* merge sort */
        int i, j, k;
        int lo;
        int md;
        int hi = 0;
        while(hi < n){
            lo = hi;                    /* set lo index */
            md = lo+sz;                 /* set md index */
            if(md >= n){                /* if single run left, copy it */
                do
                    b[lo] = a[lo];
                while(++lo < n);
                break;
            }
            hi = md+sz;                 /* set hi index */
            if(hi > n)
                hi = n;
            i = lo;                     /* merge a pair of runs */
            j = md;
            k = lo;
            while(1){
                if(a[i] <= a[j]){       /* if left <= right */
                    b[k++] = a[i++];    /*  copy element */
                    if(i < md)          /*  if not end of left run */
                        continue;       /*  continue, else copy rest of right run */
                    do
                        b[k++] = a[j++];
                    while(j < hi);
                    break;
                } else {                /* else left > right */
                    b[k++] = a[j++];    /*  copy element */
                    if(j < hi)          /*  if not end of right run */
                        continue;       /*  continue, else copy rest of left run */
                    do
                        b[k++] = a[i++];
                    while(i < md);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        t = a;                          /* swap ptrs */
        a = b;
        b = t;
    }
    free(b);                            /* free second array */
}
```